# NSOperationQueue,NSOperation

Tags: multithreading, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I m new to iphone. where i get examples for `NSOperationQueue`, `NSOperation`?
What is the advantage of `NSOperationQueue`, `NSOperation` over thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the docs. They are really good at explaining and giving examples

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1

NSOperation is easier to manage than NSThread.

Answer (score 1):

Higher level of abstraction: That is, easier to program than `NSThreads` and a little bit less control than `NSThread`.

Answer (score 0):

`NSOperationQueue`:

An `NSOperationQueue` object is a queue that handles objects of the `NSOperation` class type.
The `NSOperationQueue` handles and manages the execution of all the `NSOperation` objects (the tasks) that have been added to it. The execution takes place with the main thread of the application. When an NSOperation object is added to the queue it is executed immediately and it does not leave the queue until it is finished. A task can be cancelled, but it is not removed from the queue until it is finished.

`NSOperation`:

`NSOperation` is designed to handle more-or-less batch operations.
An `NSOperation` object, simply phrased,represents a single task, including both the data and the code related to the task.
The `NSOperation` class is an abstract one so it cannot be used directly in the program. Instead, there are two provided subclasses, the `NSInvocationOperation` class and the `NSBlockOperation` class.

OfCourse for more details [Apple iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW1) is the best option and the link below would also help to know more about it and NSOperationQueue, NSOperation VS thread.

[NSThread vs. NSOperationQueue vs. ??? on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041837/nsthread-vs-nsoperationqueue-vs-on-the-iphone?rq=1)

http://www.raywenderlich.com/19788/how-to-use-nsoperations-and-nsoperationqueues