# NSOperationQueue vs GCD

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

In what cases would you prefer to use `NSOperationQueue` over GCD?

From my limited experience of these two, I take it that with `NSOperationQueue` you basically have control over how many concurrent operations there are.

With GCD you can't do this, since you are using a queue. Except you can somehow simulate this with a multi core processor, although still I think there's no way to control it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7146052/gcd-nsoperationqueue-or-create-a-thread-manually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344884/nsoperation-vs-grand-central-dispatch

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSOperation vs Grand Central Dispatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10373331/nsoperation-vs-grand-central-dispatch)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`NSOperationQueue` is built on `GCD` as of iOS 4. Use the simplest API for the task at hand.Measure if it's a performance problem and then reevaluate if needed.`dispatch_async` is lower level, usually C-type stuff (but not limited to), and is good for one-shot and sequential type deals. NSOperationQueues are higher level, Objective-C stuff, and are good if you are adding a lot of operations at various points in your code, and/or need to manage concurrency, priorities and dependencies.

Comment: is NSOperationQueue a a higher API than GCD?

Comment: NSOperation is built on top of GCD. An NSOperation is bulky and needs more boiler-plate codes to set it up, but it has a lot more functionality. You can create the same NSOperation subclass in various parts of your code and put them into the queue and run it.

Answer (score 7):

I assume by NSPriorityQueue you mean NSOperationQueue? The main reasons to use NSOperationQueue over GCD are if you need its additional features:

- Older OS support
- KVO on operation properties
- Dependencies
- Queue width limiting (although you can do this fairly easily in GCD with dispatch_semaphore_t)

Otherwise, unless you're working with an API that takes an NSOperationQueue, GCD is probably a better bet

Answer (score 0):

Being at higher level,I found NSOperationQueue more elegant to manage tasks/operations instead of handling them at lower level using GCD.

Comment: Could you add some more detail on why you found NSOperationQueue more elegant? Without that, your answer is not helpful.