# Manual segue not transitioning properly

Tags: ipad, storyboard

I am somewhat new to ios but I've been able to muddle though... until now. I have an application with a login page. First thing I did was create a few empty view controllers and stuck them on a storyboard. I have a LoginViewController with some text fields for userId and password plus a login button. Plan is if you successfully log in you are brought to a TabViewController. Right now this is out of the box. I deleted the two view controllers that got created with it and replaced them with two NavigationControllers.

Just to test everything I made a segue from the login button to the TabViewController. Everything worked fine. Views came up. All the out of the box stuff worked.

Next step I tried to simulate an actual login. Since I have to do this through a web service call I figured it needed to be asynchronous. I deleted the initial segue I added for the login button and added a IBAction from the button to my LoginViewController. I also added a manual segue from my LoginViewController to the TabViewController and I named it "loginSegue"

Here is the code I have so far:

```
- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {
[Decorator showViewBusyIn:self.aView
            scale:1.5
        makeWhite:NO];

self.clientIdText.enabled = NO;
self.userIdText.enabled = NO;
self.passwordText.enabled = NO;
UIButton* loginBtn = sender;

loginBtn.enabled = NO;
[Decorator showViewBusyIn:self.aView
             scale:2.0
         makeWhite:NO];

self.operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
            initWithTarget:self
                  selector:@selector(doLogin)
                object:nil];
self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[self.queue addOperation:self.operation];
}

-(void)doLogin{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
    [Decorator removeBusyIndicatorFrom:self.aView];
// this is where I will eventually put the login code...
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
}
```

I put the call to sleepForTimeInterval to simulate waiting for the web service call to complete. I will remove it later. The Decorator stuff just shows and removes an Activity Indicator View.

When I do all this the segue works but the view associated with the login view controller remains on the screen. Put another way, the TabViewController shows up. The first item is selected. The NavigationController shows up but the VC associated with it and the view it contains does not appear. The view from the LoginViewController stays there.

Since all navigation worked fine when I put the segue on the login button I'm thinking it has something to do with the invocation operation. Either that or somehow my view or view controller hierarchy is getting messed up.

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?
Is this a good way to do a login?

Any help is much appreciated,
Nat

Comment: I don't really understand why but it appears that the problem is that I'm calling performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: from a thread other then the main thread. If I force the call to occur on the main thread my segue works properly. I replaced the call to performSegueWithIdentifier:sender with the following: [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(exeOnMainThread:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO]; exeOnMainThread just calls performSegueWithIdentifer:sender:
So I got it to work but I would still like to know if this is a good way to do a login.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of operation, using the GCD can be easier. You would do something like:

```
- (void)doLogin
{
    dispatch_queue_t loginQueue = dispatch_queue_create(“login”, NULL);
    dispatch_async(loginQueue, ^{         
        // this is where you will eventually put the login code...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [Decorator removeBusyIndicatorFrom:self.aView];
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
        });
    }); 
}
```

And in your `-(IBAction)login:(id)sender` you simply call `[self doLogin]` instead of

```
self.operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]
                                  initWithTarget:self
                                        selector:@selector(doLogin)
                                          object:nil];
self.queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
[self.queue addOperation:self.operation];
```

Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033465/nsoperationqueue-vs-gcd), which briefly explains what are the main differences between GCD and NSOperationQueue